# How to join two tables in SocialEngine, based on ZF

Tags: php, join, zend-framework, socialengine

My code in SocialEngine is:

```
$coreLikesTable = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('likes', 'core');
$coreLikesTableName = $coreLikesTable->info('name');

$select = $usersTable->select()->from(array('l' => 'engine4_core_likes'), array('poster_id'))->join(array('u' => 'engine4_users'), 'l.poster_id = u.user_id')->group('u.user_id');

result = $coreLikesTable->fetchAll($select);
print_r($result);die;
```

But it doesn't output anything. What's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$select = $this->_db->select()
    ->from('table1',array('col1','col2'…..))
    ->joinInner('table2','table1.id=table2.some_id',array('col1','col3'…))
    ->where('where condition here')
    ->order('column name ASC/DESC');
```